# Microsoft BI - Decision Trees - "Decision Trees Found No Splits For Model"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, classification, business-intelligence, decision-tree

I've been playing with microsoft BI data mining using decision trees alghoritm. I already know required steps to produce result. However for some data I get "Decision Trees Found No Splits For Model" at the end of the processing which results in no decision tree to be generated.

I was unable to detect what causes this. Obviously it is ms product so I am unable to look at the source code and find when the warning is triggered.

So what are the scenarios when there are no splits for a model and how to debug where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that the data cannot be divided based on any splitting of a target attribute. So the data will have the same values of the target attribute and so no tree can be built from that as there needs to be some way of saying this part of the data has this target attribute and this part has another target attribute.